# Difficulty connecting Mysql to Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot and have been attempting to connect it to my MySql workbench. I started a new Spring Boot project with web, jdbc, jpa, and hibernate, but have been stuck.

There are a number of tutorials on this subject, but they all start by indicating that it's necessary to go into the application.properties file and add a configuration similar to the below:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqltutorial?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

However, none of the tutorials I have found discusses how to find the spring.datasource.url or even the username or password.

How can I find update these application properties so my Mysql workbench will connect to my Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,
`spring.datasource.url` is equal to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqltutorial?useSSL=false`

Breaking it up:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306` is a reference to MySQL that is running locally on your machine. By default, MySQL runs on port 3306, though it can be changed if you so desire. Additionally, the address can be changed from localhost if you want to connect to a database that is running elsewhere.

`mysqltutorial` is the name of your database created in MySQL.

`?useSSL=false` is an additional property of connecting to the database.

Next,
`spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password` are the password and username you use for the database in MySQL. For a small project, you can use root, though that is not recommended for more serious projects and another user should be created with varying permissions.

Comment: so everytime i want to access a mysql database locally i use port 3306 and append the name of the database and Spring will know how to find it?

Comment: Yes, if you provide it with 'localhost' and the port it is running on Spring will be able to find it. To interact with it though (adding data, removing data, ect.) you will need to provide it with the username and password of the user you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Springboot is autotool to generate Java Config Object, like DataSource etc 's instance.

For most springboot application, if you added annotation @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication on you springboot main class, it will auto load a lot of SpringBoot's config Java class.

[image]

For your question , springboot will auto load DataSourceAutoConfiguration.
[image]

next `@EnableConfigurationProperties({DataSourceProperties.class})` will load properties from metadata class DataSourceProperties.class .

so the metadata class DataSourceProperties.class solve your problem.
[image]

Comment: do i have to import that class in my main class?

Comment: @Dog for SpringBoot , it will auo load , you just need add \@SpringbootApplication  on you main class .